# Importing Windows Live Contacts

Tags: php, msdn, windows-live

I've started with importing contacts from live. Now I don't know what MS is thinking, but they seriously do overcomplicate everything they put their hands to.

For my app, it's very important that I get a phone number. So important in fact, that should you not have a phone number, your contact is skipped. With my method I can't see any phone numbers. I assumed that it would be shown if I loop through each contact one by one, but alas, no love.

Here is my method:

```
$import_id = time();
$client_id = "xxx";
$redirect_uri = 'redirecturi';
$client_secret = "xxx";
$code = $_GET['code'];
$grant_type = "authorization_code";

$post = "client_id=$client_id&redirect_uri=$redirect_uri&client_secret=$client_secret&code=$code&grant_type=$grant_type";
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf");
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POST,5);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$token = json_decode($result);
$access_token = $token->access_token;
$user_id = $token->user_id;

$url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts?access_token=$access_token";
$response =  curl_file_get_contents($url);
$response = json_decode($response);
foreach($response->data as $contact) {
    $contact_details = curl_file_get_contents("https://apis.live.net/v5.0/" . $contact->id . "?access_token=$access_token");
    debug($contact_details);
}
die();
```

However, I'm only getting info back like this (this person I know has a contact number as I can see it when I view him on people.live.com):

```
{
   "id": "contact.id", 
   "first_name": "Danie", 
   "last_name": "Van den Heever", 
   "name": "Danie Van den Heever", 
   "is_friend": false, 
   "is_favorite": false, 
   "user_id": "userid", 
   "email_hashes": [
      "emailhash"
   ], 
   "updated_time": "2014-09-17T12:11:10+0000"
}
```

My permission request url (which defines the scopes) looks like this:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=clientidkey&scope=wl.basic%20wl.offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri=redirecturi
```

Should I add more scopes to get the contact number? If so, which scopes? Or is this not possible?

Comment: First off, ditch cURL and use a REST client library such as Guzzle, it'll transform all your cURL code (authentication, etc) into an one-liner and make your code more readable.

Comment: Well, if I can get a definite answer on this then I'll be happy. Even if it means that I can't import phone numbers. Thanks for the feedback though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use an undocumented scope `wl.contacts_phone_numbers`, there is a risk that it'll become deprecated or just locked down and only Microsoft-approved clients will be able to use it, but in the meantime it works.

Also you do not need to do an extra request for every contact, the contact object you get from `me/contacts` already has the phone numbers in a `phones` object.

By the way, here's the code I used while testing this, I used a [REST client library](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) which avoids copy/pasting the long and repetitive cURL parameters each time and turns the requests into one-liners.

Code to ask for permission :

```
$params = ["client_id" => "...", "scope" => "wl.basic wl.contacts_phone_numbers", "response_type" => "code", "redirect_uri" => "http://sanctuary/contacts_callback.php"];

header("Location: https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?".http_build_query($params));
```

Note the extra `wl.contacts_phone_numbers` scope in the permission request.

Code to get access token and retrieve contacts :

```
// Composer's autoloader, required to load libraries installed with it
// in this case it's the REST client
require "vendor/autoload.php";

// exchange the temporary token for a reusable access token
$resp = GuzzleHttp\post("https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf", ["body" => ["client_id" => "...", "client_secret" => "...", "code" => $_GET["code"], "redirect_uri" => "http://sanctuary/contacts_callback.php", "grant_type" => "authorization_code"]])->json();
$token = $resp["access_token"];

// REST client object that will send the access token by default
// avoids writing the absolute URL and the token each time
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(["base_url" => "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/", "defaults" => ["query" => ["access_token" => $token]]]);

// get all the user's contacts
$contacts = $client->get("me/contacts")->json()["data"];

// iterate over contacts
foreach ($contacts as $contact) {
    // if that contact has a phone number object
    if (array_key_exists("phones", $contact)) {
        // iterate over each phone number
        foreach ($contact["phones"] as $phone) {
            // if number isn't blank
            if (!empty($phone)) {
                // do whatever you want with that number
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's what `me/contacts` looks like with the extra scope (minus a few line breaks and personal info) :

```
Array (
    [data] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                    [id] => contact...
                    [first_name] => ...
                    [last_name] => ...
                    [name] => ...
                    [is_friend] => 
                    [is_favorite] => 
                    [user_id] => 
                    [email_hashes] => ...
                    [updated_time] => ...
                    [phones] => Array ( // what you asked for
                            [personal] => 
                            [business] => 
                            [mobile] => +337...
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Awesome! It works I been searching for this answer the whole day, thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

From reading [**the documentation**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh243648.aspx#contact), phone numbers are part of the [`User` object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh243648.aspx#user).

To fetch their phone numbers, you would;

- Grab a list of their contacts (which you've done)
- Iterate through the result set
- Grab the user id from the contact response. (Key `id`)
- Make a request to the `User` collection (with the `wl.phone_numbers` scope)
- See if the phone numbers are null or not

  - If they are NULL, skip the iteration

An example phones object (in the `User` response);

```
"phones": {
   "personal": "(555) 555-1212", 
   "business": "(555) 111-1212", 
   "mobile": null
}
```

So;

```
$arrUser = json_decode($strResponse, true);

if( is_null($arrUser['phones']['personal']) 
     AND is_null($arrUser['phones']['business']
      AND is_null($arrUser['phones']['mobile']) ) {
   //No phone numbers
   //Assuming you're in a loop, fetching a user object for each contact - skip the iteration & move onto the next contact.
   continue;
}
```

Comment: I just tried that and it doesn't return anything else besides the info already present on `me/contacts`.

Comment: @AndréDaniel Did you add the scope `wl.phone_numbers`?

Comment: @AndréDaniel Ah, sorry! I'll make a few experiments after work tonight, and update my answer later.

Comment: Will also play around with this tonight. Haven't had time as of yet. I added the bounty to this question and immediately broke my website haha. I love programming.

Comment: Tried this as well, however I got back what @AndréDaniel got back.